# si units in chemfig

Tags: chemfig, siunits

How can write si units in chemfig?

[image]

I need to put angstrom symbol instead of "A".

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
(-[:25]O-[:-25,1.3]
(-[@{e1}:20]X-[:-50,,,,draw=none]@{e2}1,781A)
-[:45,1.3])
-[:45,1.3]-[:-25,1.3]O-[@{a2}:25]
(-[@{a1}:90]
X-[:-20,1.3,,,draw=none]@{a2}1.819A)
}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
\draw(a2) -- (a1);
\draw(e2) -- (e1);
}
\end{document}
```

p.s. I have another problem: that ugly arrow starting from the top of the 1, I prefer the other arrow style.

Comment: How about `siunitx` package? `\SI{1.819}{\angstrom}` instead of 1.819 A

Comment: it works, but gives me lots of errors

Comment: I don't know why but it gives me no error now

Comment: Good news then! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `siunitx` works very well, so I would use it: `\SI{1.819}{\angstrom}`. To change what you call the arrow style you can just make the line to start from one of the several anchors that TikZ automatically defines when you draw a node. To access them use the syntax `<node_name>.anchor` where anchor can be `south`, `east`, `west`, `north` and  `center` (in this case `west` is the most appropriate).

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{
(-[:25]O-[:-25,1.3]
(-[@{e1}:20]X-[:-50,,,,draw=none]@{e2}\SI{1,781}{\angstrom})
-[:45,1.3])
-[:45,1.3]-[:-25,1.3]O-[@{a2}:25]
(-[@{a1}:90]
X-[:-20,1.3,,,draw=none]@{a2}\SI{1.819}{\angstrom})
}
\schemestop
\chemmove{
\draw[-stealth](a2) -- (a1);
\draw[-stealth](e2.west) -- (e1);
}
\end{document}
```

[image: desired output]

Comment: Works like a charme! I don't know what happened, but it works.

Comment: what about that convert option in documentclass?

Comment: My bad, I used it to attach the png image to this answer. It is absolutely unnecessary and now I've removed it.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `chemfig` would load `tikz`, which is why I commented that line.

Comment: I am interested in images from standalone documentclass, I will search for some documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

To print angstrom symbol use `\AA` in math mode instead  of `A`

So it will be something like

```
(-[@{e1}:20]X-[:-50,,,,draw=none]@{e2}1,781$\AA$)
```

instead of

```
(-[@{e1}:20]X-[:-50,,,,draw=none]@{e2}1,781A)
```

Gotta admit that this throw some error, but it is rendered properly in my place. So I think you can just ignore it.

Comment: Same as \SI : lots of errors, but it works. I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but a solution which throws errors is a bad solution. The macro `\AA` (which translates to `\r{A}`) works only in text mode. The arguments of `\chemfig` are already in math mode, so adding `$...$` makes things only worse. If you don't want to use `siunitx` or `amsmath`, at least replace your `$\AA$` by `\mbox{\AA}`.

Comment: No offense taken. Honestly, that is some interesting tidbit  of information. Can confirm that using `\mbox{\AA}` instead `$\AA$` will compile the document properly without error.